# Ebay Scraper, missing date for first line and then evey loop

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am having issues with my eBAY Scraper and can not work out why. Although it is pulling the data off fine, it misses SOME of the data OFF for the first row and then for each first row of every Loop and therefore the data is not in the correct row.

**Q)** *Why is it missing the data at the start and then for each loop?*

I think It may have something to do with the title extracting slower that the rest of the items, however I can not work it out as I am very limited with vba. I have attached a demo, for your viewing.

I am not looking for a full rewite of the code, just pointing in the right direction or a SLIGHT change to MY code. As I stated I and very limited in vba, I can understand my code, anything more advanced will be out of my depth.

**Demo Download** - [Download Excel File](https://app.box.com/s/1ip00rijsg1zhkg6oko47bpby8nzgbrh)

**WebSite**  - [Ebay.co.uk](https://www.ebay.co.uk/)

**Ebay Product Page -** [Prodcts Shown may vary browser to browser](https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=phone&_sacat=0)

I have colour coded it so you can see better

**This is what it is doing**
[image: Image1 Error]

**When It Should be This**
[image: Image 2 Correct]

For some reason it misses out **Price, Condition, Former Price & Discount** for the first item on start and **EVERY Loop**. For every loop that it misses the items out the **Price, Condition, Former Price & Discount** become MORE out of line

**1st Loop**  - Items are NOW **2** rows out of line
[image: Loop1]

**2nd Loop**  - Items are NOW **3** rows out of line
[image: Loop2]

As I searched 3 pages (2 pages + 1 extra) and it looped 3 time it has missed the first row on each loop. I am 3 rows out. I think this may have too do with the **Title** of the item as it extracts a bit slower then the rest of the items

**End Of Extraction**
[image: End Results]

This is my code

```
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim objIE As Object
Dim result As String
Dim pageNumber As Long ' page no.
Dim nextPageElement As Object 'page element
Dim HtmlText As Variant
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'+++++ Internet Explorer ++++++
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
        objIE.Visible = False
        objIE.navigate Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & Replace(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") & Range("C2").Value, " ", "+") 'navigate IE to this web page

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'######################################## RESTART CODE FROM HERE ####################################
StartForLoop_Restart: 'Restart the code HERE, this is the key part
'######################################## RESTART CODE FROM HERE ####################################

    '  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set HTML = objIE.document
        Set elements = HTML.getElementsByClassName("s-item__wrapper clearfix") ' parent CLASS
        'FOR LOOP
        For Each element In elements
    
''' Element 1
        If element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__link")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__link")(0).href
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = HtmlText
        End If
''' Element 2
        If element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__link")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__link")(0).innerText  'src
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Value = HtmlText
        End If
''' Element 3
        If element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__price")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "C").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__price")(0).innerText
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "C").Value = HtmlText
        End If
''' Element 4
        If element.getElementsByClassName("SECONDARY_INFO")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "D").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("SECONDARY_INFO")(0).innerText
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "D").Value = HtmlText
        End If
''' Element 5
        If element.getElementsByClassName("STRIKETHROUGH")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "E").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("STRIKETHROUGH")(0).innerText
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "E").Value = HtmlText
        End If
''' Element 6
        If element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__discount s-item__discount")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "F").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__discount s-item__discount")(0).innerText
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "F").Value = HtmlText
        End If
   ' Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Next element

    Do
    'Searches Number of Pages entered in
    If pageNumber >= Replace(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d2").Value, "", "+") Then Exit Do
        Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("pagination__next")(0) ' CLICK TO NEXT PAGE
    If nextPageElement Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        objIE.document.parentWindow.Scroll 0&, 99999 ' Scrolls Down the Browser
        nextPageElement.Click 'next web page
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4
   
    Loop
        Set HTML = objIE.document
        pageNumber = pageNumber + 1

'##################################### Restart Loop ##################################
 GoTo StartForLoop_Restart ' use GOTo command and label to reinitiate the CODE AS WOULD NOT LOOP TO NEXT PAGE
'##################################### Restart Loop ##################################

     Loop

        objIE.Quit ' end and clear browser
            Set objIE = Nothing
            Set HTML = Nothing
            Set nextPageElement = Nothing
            Set HtmlText = Nothing
            Set element = Nothing

End Sub
```

As always thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to skip the first element within your returned collection. Keeping to your code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim result As String
    Dim pageNumber As Long                       ' page no.
    Dim nextPageElement As Object                'page element
    Dim HtmlText As Variant
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    '+++++ Internet Explorer ++++++
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & Replace(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") & Range("C2").Value, " ", "+") 'navigate IE to this web page

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    'Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    '######################################## RESTART CODE FROM HERE ####################################
StartForLoop_Restart:                            'Restart the code HERE, this is the key part
    '######################################## RESTART CODE FROM HERE ####################################

    '  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set HTML = objIE.document
    Set elements = HTML.getElementsByClassName("s-item__wrapper clearfix") ' parent CLASS
    'FOR LOOP
    Dim counter As Long
    counter = 0
    
    For Each element In elements
        If counter > 0 Then
        ''' Element 1
        If element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__link")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__link")(0).href
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = HtmlText
        End If
        ''' Element 2
        If element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__link")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__link")(0).innerText 'src
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Value = HtmlText
        End If
        ''' Element 3
        If element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__price")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "C").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__price")(0).innerText
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "C").Value = HtmlText
        End If
        ''' Element 4
        If element.getElementsByClassName("SECONDARY_INFO")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "D").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("SECONDARY_INFO")(0).innerText
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "D").Value = HtmlText
        End If
        ''' Element 5
        If element.getElementsByClassName("STRIKETHROUGH")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "E").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("STRIKETHROUGH")(0).innerText
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "E").Value = HtmlText
        End If
        ''' Element 6
        If element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__discount s-item__discount")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "F").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("s-item__discount s-item__discount")(0).innerText
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "F").Value = HtmlText
        End If
        ' Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Next element
    
    Do
        'Searches Number of Pages entered in
        If pageNumber >= Replace$(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d2").Value, "", "+") Then Exit Do
        
        Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("pagination__next")(0) ' CLICK TO NEXT PAGE
        
        If nextPageElement Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        
        objIE.document.parentWindow.Scroll 0&, 99999 ' Scrolls Down the Browser
        nextPageElement.Click                    'next web page
        
        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
        Loop
        
        Set HTML = objIE.document
        
        pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
        counter = 0
        '##################################### Restart Loop ##################################
        GoTo StartForLoop_Restart                ' use GOTo command and label to reinitiate the CODE AS WOULD NOT LOOP TO NEXT PAGE
        '##################################### Restart Loop ##################################

    Loop

    objIE.Quit                                   ' end and clear browser
    Set objIE = Nothing
    Set HTML = Nothing
    Set nextPageElement = Nothing
    Set HtmlText = Nothing
    Set element = Nothing

End Sub
```